# Capitalization of keyboard shortcuts

Tags: gui-design

When displaying actions performed by a keyboard shortcut, wether through tooltip, display beside the menu item or on a help guide, what casing should be used?

- <kbd>CTRL+L</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL+l</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl+l</kbd>
- <kbd>ctrl+L</kbd>
- <kbd>ctrl+l</kbd>

Is there a standard around this?  Or is this just what's commonly used or more of 'it depends on what you feel like'?

Comment: I am not sure if it a windows app, but think of the mac users as well :)

Comment: @DimitraMiha, I'm trying to get a sense outside of a specific medium, wether it be native to an OS or through the web.

Answer (score 2):

There's no standard.

Of course there are style guides for a lot of places that tell you how to treat abbreviations.

One word of advice: lowercase letters can sometimes be hard to distinguish, so sometimes caps are better.

<kbd>CTRL+l</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL+I</kbd> look the same on stackexchange at first glance.